# REACT JS : Uncaught Error: parse Error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react (I am incorporating it into my ruby on rails project), here the component ive made:

```
  <div id="articles"></div>
  <script type="text/jsx">



var Article=React.createClass({
    render: function(){
         return(
           <div>
             {this.props.data}.map(function(item){
               {item.name}  
             })
           </div>
         )
    }
});




var input = [{name: "hello", email: "hello@example.com"}]

React.render(<Article data={input} />, document.getElementById("articles"))
```

When i run this, this is the error i get:

```
Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 7: Unexpected token .

{item.name}
```

I have set a prop to be an array. I just want to output the name hash key inside the array - why am i getting this error, it seems to me that this should work ?

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning anything inside your map-statement, try writing

```
return {item.name};
```

However, I would suggest you try moving your map-function outside of the immediate render, its easier to read and less error-prone.

```
 <div id="articles"></div>
  <script type="text/jsx">

var Article=React.createClass({
    render: function() {
         var rows = this.props.data.map(function(item) {
               //You could return any valid jsx here, like <span>{item.name}</span>
               return item.name;
         });
         return(
           <div>  
               {rows}
           </div>
         )
    }
});

var input = [{name: "hello", email: "hello@example.com"}
React.render(<Article data={input} />, document.getElementById("articles"))
```

Answer (score 2):

In JSX you have two 'modes'. JS mode (default) and JSX mode.

You enter JSX mode with a tag, like `<div`. In JSX mode only tags, attributes, and arbitrary text are allowed. You are also allowed to go into a JS mode with `{}`. This can happen any number of times.

```
function jsMode(){
    <jsx>
        {js(
            moreJs,
            <moreJsx>{evenMoreJs}</moreJsx>
        )}
    </jsx>;
}
```

So coming back to your code:

```
<div>
    {this.props.data}.map(function(item){
        {item.name}  
    })
</div>
```

Let's break this down into chunks

```
// js mode
<div> // begin jsx
{ // begin js
    this.props.data // some js code
} // end js, back to jsx
.map(function(item) // this is just plain text visible to the user
{ // begin js
{item.name} // some invalid js, SyntaxError
} // end js
) // this is just plain text visible to the user
</div> // end jsx
// js mode
```

Because you want the .map to be interpreted as JS, and you were previously in JSX mode, it should also be in the `{}s`.

```
<div>
    {this.props.data.map(function(item){
        {item.name}  
    })}
</div>
```

Also, inside the .map callback, you're still in JS mode, so you need to remove the `{}s`

```
<div>
    {this.props.data.map(function(item){
        item.name
    })}
</div>
```

And finally, you need to return the name from the .map callback.

```
<div>
    {this.props.data.map(function(item){
        return item.name;
    })}
</div>
```

#### Other stuff

The code above will work, but probably not as expected.

If data was `[{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}]`, map will return `['foo', 'bar']`, and react will render it as:

```
<span>foo</span><span>bar</span>
```

To the user this appears as "foobar". If you want it to appear as two separate words you could put a space after each name:

```
<div>
    {this.props.data.map(function(item){
        return item.name + " ";
    })}
</div>
```

Or return an element from .map and style it as you like. For example, an unordered list of names. Note that here we wrap `item.name` in `{}s` because we enter JSX mode.

```
<ul>
    {this.props.data.map(function(item, i){
        return <li key={i}>{item.name}</li>;
    })}
</ul>
```

We also provide a key. In this case it's the index of the item, which works as long as the list never changes, or only has items added/removed to/from the end of the array.

[image: picture of stack data structure]

<sup><sup>Image credit: wikipedia/commons</sup></sup>

If the array is reordered, or items are added/remove to/from the start or middle, we need a unique string identifier for each item.

If your data was `[{name: "foo", id: "14019751"}, {name: "bar", id: "13409185"}]`, then:

```
<ul>
    {this.props.data.map(function(item, i){
        return <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>;
    })}
</ul>
```